# Get the returned data from $.post data outside he post area

Tags: jquery

I have this `$.post` statement, I wanted to get the function outside the `$.post` data.

```
$(function(){
   var new_data = '';
   $.post('my_url', {}, function(data){
       new_data = data;
   });

   console.log(new_data);
});
```

This is what I did, but it does not give an output, the data im getting is a `json_encoded` data from `PHP` how can I get the data outside of the `$.post` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you extrapolate out the logging or not, it will still need to be in the callback of the `.post`.

You'll need to either put your logging directly inside the callback of the `.post`:

```
$(function() {
  var new_data = '';
  $.post('my_url', {}, function(data) {
    new_data = data;
    console.log(new_data);
  });
});
```

Or make the callback reference an external function:

```
$(function() {
  var new_data = '';
  $.post('my_url', {}, function(data) {
    new_data = data;
    response(new_data);
  });
});

function response(new_data) {
  console.log(new_data);
}
```